# The type or namespace name 'ARSubsystemManager' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.XR'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I have been following the example from:

https://github.com/shaqian/TF-Unity-ARFoundation

try to make an AR-ML android application, however there are some errors.
I solved some of them but this one keep appearing:

Assets\Scripts\CameraConfigController.cs(4,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ARSubsystemManager' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.XR' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The project included follow packages:

AR Foundation 4.17

AR Subsystems 4.17

ARCore XR Plugin 4.17

ARCore Extensions 1.25.0

What can I do to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub you are using has been updated last 2 years ago. It's probably a Unity version issue, I dont know which unity version you are using but I expect you need a 2017 or 2018 versions.
XR has changed a lot over the last years so a lot is deprecated.